# Aceitar somente números em um input no python

Tags: python

oii!
estou tenatando fazer um jogo de tabuada, mas se o usuario não digita um numero o codigo da erro... como faço pra ele reconhecer o erro e informar ao usuario para digitar somente numeros (na minha variavel 'resposta')?

```
while contador < 5:
    contador = contador + 1
    num1 = randint(0,6)
    num2 = randint(0,6)
    resposta = input(f'{num1} x {num2} = ')
    resolva = num1 * num2
    if int(resposta) == resolva:
        contador2 = contador2 + 1
    if int(resposta) != resolva:
        print(f'Péen! Na verdade é {resolva}')
```

Comment: Em vez de dois if's (um pra ver se é igual e outro pra ver se é diferente), poderia ser um `if`/`else`. Em vez de converter para `int` várias vezes, faça apenas uma vez, e verifique se deu erro usando um `try`/`except`, assim: https://ideone.com/nJtfgn

Comment: @hkotsubo muito obrigada, estou estudando ainda mas me ajudou muito, obrigada!

Answer (score -3):

from random import randint

contador = 0
while contador <=5:
contador = contador + 1
num1 = randint(0,6)
num2 = randint(0,6)
resposta = input(f'{num1} x {num2} = ')
resolva = num1 * num2
if int(resposta) == resolva:
contador2 = contador2 + 1
if int(resposta) != resolva:
print(f'Péen! Na verdade é {resolva}')

O erro era uma variável contador não defenida

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

O próprio python dá erro quando é feita uma comparação de duas variaveis de tipos diferentes.

- O Python dá erro se tentares comparar string com int

Para lançar uma mensagem personalizada bastaria colocar as comparações (os ifs) dentro de um try.

*Exemplo Parte alterada do Programa*

```
try:
    if int(resposta) == resolva:
        contador2 = contador2 + 1
    if int(resposta) != resolva:
        print(f'Péen! Na verdade é {resolva}')
except:
    print('Tens de introduzir um número inteiro')
```

**Com a alteração a baixo resolve diretamente o teu problema**

- Não alterei nada no código original apenas adicionei o try

**Vantagens de utilizar o try**

- Permite que o código continue a funcionar depois de um erro
- Permite-te preparar o código para que te diga exatamente qual o erro que está a acontecer.